# REPLACE INTO and ON DUPLICATE UPDATE is not working

Tags: mysql

I have Tables T1 and weekly like below:

```
CREATE TABLE T1 (
  C1 varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  C2 varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  timestamp timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
);
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE weekly (
  C1 varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  C2 varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  year year(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  week int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  count int(11)
);
```

Basically, I want to sum of all values group by c1, c2 per year and per week. Need to store those values to "weekly" table. This query should run every day and replace if the entry is already exists.

So I tried to use replace into.

```
replace into weekly select year(timestamp) as year,  week(timestamp) as week, C1, C2,  count(*) as count  from T1  where timestamp >= 20130606 and timestamp <= 20130613 group by C1,C2;
```

But this query is adding new entry into the weekly table and not replacing it. What is wrong?

Comment: You have the order of the fields mixed up in your query.

Comment: Firstly, without a primary key, you cannot expect `ON DUPLICATE KEY` to work. This is obvious, just look at the phrase (on duplicate _key_). Secondly, I don't think `REPLACE INTO` can be used with `ON DUPLICATE KEY` because replace tries to operate on a row matched by key(s) as well as on duplicate key. So in this case you are instructing MySQL to do two clashing operations.

Comment: @MarcellFülöp: Does it need to be `PRIMARY`, or just `UNIQUE`?

Comment: Good question! I think primary but the same to work for unique would make sense too.

Answer (score 1):

You need keys for replace to work as you intend.

> REPLACE works exactly like INSERT, except that if an old row in the table has the same    value as a new row for a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE index, the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted. See Section 13.2.5, “INSERT Syntax”.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replace.html